# multiple ToggleButton on listView items. When one is clicked, others get turned on/off

Tags: android, adapter, togglebutton

I have a list view with several ToggleButton items. When I click one, another gets turned on/off. However, it executes the action related to the right ListView item.

They are managed in a custom adapter, I here is my code:

```
public class AdapterContacts extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

ToggleButton btnIsSending;
     .
     .
     .

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Contact entry = contactsList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null);
    }
     .
     .
     .
   // isSending button
    btnIsSending = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnIsSending);
    btnIsSending.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    btnIsSending.setFocusable(false);
    btnIsSending.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnIsSending.setTag(entry);

    return convertView;
}

    public void onClick(View view) {
    final Contact entry = (Contact) view.getTag();
    Log.d(TAG, "entry " + entry.getPhoneNr());

    LookalizeData lookData = (LookalizeApp.getContext()).lookalizeData;
    // Toggle send button
    if( view.getId() == btnIsSending.getId()){
        if(btnIsSending.isChecked())
             ...
        else
                     ... 
      }
```

There are  other buttons and they work fine.

Any idea or experience to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `getView` you have to something like this (this code is give you an idea how it will work in your case):

```
ListView lv = ((ListActivity)context).getListView();
// Containing all check states
SparseBooleanArray sba = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

btnIsSending = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnIsSending);
btnIsSending.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
btnIsSending.setFocusable(false);
btnIsSending.setTag(entry);

btnIsSending.setChecked(false);

// Cursor is passed as an argument.
if(sba != null)
  if(sba.get(cursor.getPosition()))
     btnIsSending.setChecked(true);
```

That said this what you need on the Activity side.

You have make your ListView to multi-selection mode by android:choiceMode in xml or using setChoiceMode.

You have to remove your `onClick` listener on buttons. Whatever you doing in `onClick` of button, you have to add that logic to the `onListItemClick` of `ListActivtiy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really get this code and don't knnow how to use the sparseBooleanArray. I will try this. As a temp fix, I have set an independant onClickListener fot my toggle button.